# page reloads after submitting in codeigniter while using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am not very familiar with ajax in codeigniter. I simply want to display the first name and last name I just entered inside the div with id(result). But when I click submit, the page only reloads. What is wrong ? Thanks in advance.
Well this is my view file `employee.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
    <h1><?php echo lang('employee:insert'); ?></h1>
    <div class="form_box">
        <?php

            echo form_open(); //form open

            echo form_label('First Name: ', 'fn');
            $data = array('name' => 'first_name','type' => 'text', 'id' =>'first_name');
            echo form_input($data)."<br>";

            echo form_label('Last Name: ', 'ln');
            $data = array('name' => 'last_name','type' => 'text', 'id' => 'last_name');
            echo form_input($data)."<br>";

            $data = array('type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Submit', 'id' => 'submit');
            echo form_submit($data);

            echo form_close(); // form close
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="result">
    here 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var first_name: $('input#first_name').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/employee/insert'); ?>",
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {name: first_name},
                success: function(data) {
                    if(res) {
                        $("div#result").html(res.un);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my controller file `admin.php`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends Admin_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->lang->load("employee");
        $this->load->model('emp_model');

        $this->template
            ->append_css("module::admin.css")
            ->append_js("module::admin.js")
            ->append_js("module::jquery-2.2.3.min.js");
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->template->build("admin/employee");
    }

    public function insert() {
        $data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name')
            );

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: change input type submit to input type button or use .submit instead of .click

Comment: The page reloading stopped but I'm still nowhere. Even after clicking the submit button nothing happens. The ajax function is not working.

Comment: Is your ajax fired ?  Do you see any errors in console ?

Comment: yes. the console says "500 internal error"

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax you are sending only one parameter `data: {name: first_name},` 
and you are fetching both in controller which is generating internal server error .. see here in controller, you didn't send `$this->input->post('last_name');` from your ajax request

**Your Mistake** : You are sending only one parameter from ajax request i.e. 'name' and in controller you are fetching first_name,last_name. Also you are sending request to wrong url, why are you using **employee** in the url ?? `<?php echo site_url('admin/employee/insert'); ?>`

Try sending both parameters something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var first_name = $('input#first_name').val();
            var last_name = $('input#last_name').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo site_url('admin/insert'); ?>",
                dataType: 'text',
                data: {'first_name': first_name,'last_name':last_name},
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {
                        $("div#result").html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note : I added  `var last_name: $('input#last_name').val();` in your ajax post request and changed this `{name: first_name}`  to `data: {'first_name': first_name,'last_name':last_name}`

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thanks it works... and about "employee" in url, I am working on Pyrocms module development, so it's my module name. Thanks again.